# Multiple conditions with contains in power automate desktop

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I want to evaluate multiple conditions in one If statement in Power Automate Desktop. I have been able to do it with the basic operators (=, >, <, <>, etc.) and using IsEmpty. But I have not found any documentation about how to use it with these:

- Contains
- Does not contain
- Starts with
- Doesn't start with
- Ends with
- Doesn't end with

I would like to evaluate something like this:

```
%strFileContents Contains 'word' and strFilePath Does not contain '.txt'%
```

I know that I can achieve this with multiple ifs but I would like to know if it can be done in a single one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%Contains(strFileContents, 'Word', True) AND NOT(Contains(strFilePath,'.txt.))%
```

You can add as many `AND` or `OR` as you like to evaluate the condition.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Do you know where I can find any documentation about how to use those conditions like this one?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Often just have to "Figure it out"